# Looking for a good SSH apps for iPhone

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, ssh

I have been using a free SSH app on my phone for a little while but stopped because using VIM mostly broke it. Now after some updates I seems to have a limited number of key strokes before it expires. So now seems like a good time to shop around.

There are the requirements:

- Can emulate color
- Can run VIM, though being able to run EMACS would be cool too.
- It does not have to be free.
- it must run on a non jail broken phone.

What is everyone else using? What do you suggest?

Comment: What is the name of your current SSH app?

Comment: @VxJasonxV - thanks for the edit. ZaTelnet is was i was using before.

Comment: Once you try this, you will realize you cannot do any serious work on Vim or Emacs.  It's very handy in a pinch, but it's not practical.  IMHO, of course.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Being the fanboy that I am, I completely admit that I am absolutely in love with [Prompt](http://www.panic.com/blog/2011/04/introducing-prompt-ssh-for-ios/) (by [Panic](http://www.panic.com)). It's already come a long way since it's initial release, and here's a few wonderful features;

1. It's not cluttered. They provided an app that offers what you need out of an SSH client and added a few bonuses that make it so much more worthwhile.
2. Command, and parameter, auto-completion. (Oh my god this is *amazing*.)
3. Public/Private key authentication support. Well documented, and also quite improved in recent versions with regard to how to load the actual key.
4. Leveraging the amount of free space in the meta key bar, you can assign 4 "favorite special character keys", so pick the ones you use most often so you rarely have to hit the <kbd>123</kbd> keyboard key, or worse, the <kbd>#+=</kbd> key. I currently have <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> chosen.

Prompt is $8 (universal app!) on the [iTunes App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8).

Comment: It's not just the best iOS SSH app, it's one of the best mobile SSH clients I've used on any device.

Comment: Note for those finding there way here from Google...Prompt is very nice, but lacks sash agent support.  Depending on how you usually work this can be annoying.  I use Prompt anyway, but this keeps biting me.

Comment: ssh-agent support is a moot point and nigh impossible to run on software that does not run persistently. Besides, SSH Agent times out after a certain period of time, and background software expires after a period of time. The implementation is surprisingly similar when you think about it.

Comment: Its not just $7. Its also $8 minus a penny. Thats's a pizza!

Comment: @chillin [and always has been](http://appshopper.com/utilities/prompt-2) when not on sale, huh. Yup, I screwed that up. Weird. Oh well, fixed now.

Answer (score 10):

I've been using [Panic's Prompt](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8).  It does color, SSH keys (including PEMs, if you've got a need to work with EC2), runs Vim and Emacs just fine, and most definitely works beautifully on a non-jailbroken phone.  The soft keyboard also provides convenient access to escape, tab, and other keys that you need frequently when you're working with a terminal.  Properly configured, Prompt also provides superb auto-complete that actually makes using a terminal on an iPhone palatable.  Alternatively, Prompt works great with a Bluetooth keyboard--a combination that has proved excellent when I'm on the road and something goes wrong with a server.

Plus, Prompt is a universal app, so if you've got an iPad, you can use the bigger screen when you've got it, and still rely on the iPhone's size when you don't.

My only complaint is that Prompt can be a bit slow.  I'm not sure how much of that is Prompt's fault, and how much of that is my cell phone's network not being quite up-to-snuff.  But the slowness hasn't honestly

Comment: Great minds think alike?

Comment: I like that we posted literally three seconds apart and identified exactly the same features to boot.  Do you also find Prompt a bit slow, though?

Comment: The slowness is partially CPU clock rate limited and how any iOS app that has to wait for data from the network. Latency kills the fluid feel of ssh no matter if it's a computer or iOS client. You can use prompt on a fast network (especially iPad on 802.11n) to see the true speed of the prompt app - it screams when the network is fast - even on older devices.

Comment: I had worse problems with iSSH. In addition to bmike's statements, I've used prompt more often on my (WiFi Only) iPad. And much less frequently across the internet than local network connections. I have certainly seen the same kind of inherent latency, but it's nowhere near the worst I've seen, such as SSH'ing into a saturated network.

As long as an app responds better than that situation, I'm happy. And in Prompt's case, I'm freaking ecstatic.

Answer (score 5):

I like [iSSH](http://www.zinger-soft.com/iSSH_features.html). It's been around a long time and is a high quality emulator. It's usable on an iPhone screen and quite nice on an iPad screen. It even has a workaround for using the Control key on an external Bluetooth keyboard. I also tried Prompt right when it was released and found it not as solid, although it's had a lot of improvements since then.

Comment: iSSH is far and away my favorite.  The developer will even add features if you request them in email or through the iSSH google group.

Comment: issh has [MOSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosh_(software)) support!

Comment: I just want to note that iSSH, which was indeed the best ssh app around, has been discontinued and, as far as I can tell, removed from the app store.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Server Auditor](http://www.serverauditor.com). It's the best terminal for using Emacs from your iPhone. It allows to do C-x C-s without pain. It's also available on Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

Panic's Prompt is noticeably much slower than iSSH. If that doesn't bother you, it's a nice, simple SSH terminal app.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. It's generally a good idea to post some corroborating evidence on answer, especially if they might seem...contentious and somewhat speculative. As the above does.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a new one called [RapidSSH](http://www.rapidssh.com/) that is pretty good

- Supports SSH Agent and Agent Forwarding
- Really easy and comprehensive key management
- Supports multi-session and has good cut and paste slide out
- Integrates with Dropbox so you can get big lumps of text into, and log files out of the app really easily.

Also has loads of other features which I dont really use, but as OP requested- it runs vIM, does ANSI colour, emacs is not that good, isn't free but very cheap and runs on non-jailbroken phones fine.

Answer (score 1):

try **[xCute](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcute/id809286174)** - a new and existing SSH app for iPad / iPhone

Quotation from **xCute** web page:

> Sending commands to a server can be as simple as sending a text
>   message to a friend.
>
> ```
>    Remote SSH asynchronous execution.  
>
>    Results displayed back. 
>
>    Persistent host details.   
>
>    User defined sets for keyword colouring output.   
>
>    Scripts for one touch execution.   
>
>    iCloud on demand synchronisation.   
>
>    Global or on a per user/server secure connections.
> ```

The application is available in English, Spanish and French

Extremely easy to use, just type a command or chose from your own list of scripts, and hit send.

Changing server is also extremely easy.

I like the colouring output, one can distinguish easily between commands and output, and can selectively colour words in the output which help my presentations which I can email with all that formatting.

Comment: Why is it better than others in your experience not quotes from the sellers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please read the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and include a disclaimer if you are the author of the product in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with iSSH is that it has quite a lot of ui bugs. Input disappearing behind the keyboard and such. Also the ui is not really ios standard.. It has got me searching for alternatives a few times. (Why I'm here)
Other than that, good client. Also does VNC quite good.

Answer (score -2):

Why not try ssh term pro? It best in many case than above apps

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation, could you defend your argument in any way? Why do you think it's better?

Answer (score -2):

**[vSSH](http://www.velestar.com/Pages/VSSHIOSPage.aspx)** - advanced ssh and telnet client for iPhone and iPad. In addition to standard iOS ssh client functions (background work, port forwarding, key forwarding, unicode and pseudographics support, sessions logging) has the following unique features:

- Touch screen gestures (configurable, simulates arrow Pg Up/Down and other key combination)
- Extended keyboard (configurable, F1-F20, Ctrl, Alt, Ins, Pg Up/Down and other keys)
- Full-featured external (bluetooth) keyboard support (including modifier keys)
- iCloud sync between all iOS devices as well as [OS X](http://www.velestar.com/Pages/VSSHOSXPage.aspx) app version
- Macros support (you shell scripts as menu items for quick access)

Free lite (with Ad) version is available.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please read the help center regarding [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and include a disclaimer if you are the author of the product in your answer.